# Why is it not possible to pass a <?> or a <? extends T> generic class instance to a method expecting a <? super T>?

Tags: java, generics, extends, super

The PECS principle is about what kind of argument you select in a function, depending on how you will use that parameter.
My question is about the fact that, once you chose to use `super` (because your function possibly is a Consumer), you cannot pass to that function certain generic class instances.

Let's consider the following program:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<?> unbound = new ArrayList<Long>();
        List<? extends Long> extendsBound = new ArrayList<Long>();
        List<? super Long> superBound = new ArrayList<Long>();

        takeExtend(unbound);
        takeExtend(extendsBound);
        takeExtend(superBound);

        takeSuper(unbound);
        takeSuper(extendsBound);
        takeSuper(superBound);
    }

    static <T> void takeExtend(List<? extends T> l){}
    static <T> void takeSuper(List<? super T> l){}
}
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
error: method takeSuper in class Main cannot be applied to given
types;
        takeSuper(unbound);
        ^   required: List<? super T>   found: List<CAP#1>   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; List<CAP#1> cannot be converted to List<? super T>)   where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>takeSuper(List<? super T>)   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

I was trying to find a sort of symmetry, such as the one we have for the PECS rule, but I didn't find any.
So:

- Why is it not possible to pass a `<?>` or a `<? extends T>` to a function expecting `<? super T>`?
- Why is it possible to pass a `<?>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?
- Why is it possible to pass a `<? super T>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?

Comment: I already got the PECS principle, but this question is about his application to different kind of generics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough before commenting. I removed my comment; I agree it's not the same.

Comment: What's your Java version? This works in Java 8 and above.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8.0_60, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I kind of think this compiler error is a bug. It should do capture conversion and then infer that `T` is `CAP#1`. A `List<CAP#1>` is a `List<? super CAP#1>` so it should be fine. Here's a way around it by doing the capture conversion in a separate step: http://ideone.com/DBefuU.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a generic method (i.e. a method with its own type parameters) as making a set of statements about its type parameters.

For example, the method **`<T> someMethod(List<T>)`** is saying:

> There exists some type `T` for which the type parameter of this list equals `T`.

Easy. All lists fit this criterion, so any list is a valid input to the method.

Everything inside the method can now make use of the knowledge that that statement is true. How is that knowledge useful? Well, if we get an item from the list, we know it matches the list's type parameter. Because we captured the type as `T`, we can hold a reference to the object and *put it back in the list later*, all still without knowing what type it really is.

The method declaration **`<T> someMethod(List<? extends T>)`** makes a slightly different claim:

> There exists some type `T` for which the type parameter of this list is a subtype of `T`.

This is also trivially true for all lists. However, you might notice that it makes `<T> someMethod(List<? extends T>)` a bit useless. You're telling the compiler to capture the fact that items that come out of the list share some common supertype with other items that come out of the list. Unless you have, inside the method, some other consumer that is known to accept `<? super T>`, there's nothing you can do with that information. It's much less useful than the knowledge that all the items that come from the list are of the same type.

---

**So, why doesn't `<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)` work the same way?**

The method declaration **`<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)`** can be interpreted as claiming that:

> There exists some type `T` for which the type parameter of this list is a supertype of `T`.

If we have a `List<? super Long>` and we pass it to a method that captures `<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)` it's easy to see that a reference of type `Long` would satisfy `T`. We could pass a `Long` to the method as a parameter of type `T`, and then add it to the list from inside the method.

But what about if we have a `List<?>` and we capture its type using the method `<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)`? By declaring the list as a `List<?>` we're saying that we don't currently know what its type parameter is. In doing that, we're telling the compiler that we have absolutely no way to get a reference of a type that matches the type parameter of the list. In other words, the compiler knows with certainty that ***no object can satisfy the type parameter `T`***. Remember, for this method, an object is of type `T` if it is *known* to be of a type that is a subtype of the type parameter of the list. If we don't know *anything* about the type parameter of the list, that's impossible.

The same is true for a `List<? extends Long>`. We know that the items we fetch from the list will be a subtype of `Long`, but we don't have a *lower* bound for their type. We can never prove that any type is a subtype of the list's type parameter. So, for the method `<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)`, there is again provably no way to get a reference of type `T`.

Interestingly, my compiler (Java 8) doesn't complain about calling the method `<T> takeSuper(List<? super T>)` with a `List<?>` as input. I suppose it recognizes that since there's no way to get a reference of type `T`, there's no harm in just ignoring the useless type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it not possible to pass a `<?>` or a `<? extends T>` to a function expecting `<? super T>`?

Consider this method:

```
static <T> void sillyAdd(List<? super T> l, T t){
  l.add(t);
}
```

Now look how we could use it if this were possible:

```
List<Integer> onlyIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Number> anyNumber = onlyIntegers;
sillyAdd(anyNumber, Float.valueOf(0)); /* Not allowed... */
Integer i = onlyIntegers.get(0);
```

The last line would throw a `ClassCastException` because we were allowed to put a `Float` into a `List<Integer>`.

> Why is it possible to pass a `<?>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?

```
takeExtend(unbound);
```

There are no bounds on `T`; it could be any type. While the type parameter of `unbound` is *unknown*, it does have *some* type, and since `T` can be any type, it's a match.

Methods like this are sometimes used as a helper in some odd corners of generics. Logically, we know that the following should be no problem:

```
public static void rotate(List<?> l) {
  l.add(l.remove(0));
}
```

But the rules of generics don't imply type-safety here. Instead, we can use a helper like this:

```
public static void rotate(List<?> l) {
  helper(l);
}

private static <T> void helper(List<T> l) {
  l.add(l.remove(0));
}
```

> Why is it possible to pass a `<? super T>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?

It's not, in a way. Given this example:

```
static <T> void takeExtend(List<? extends T> l)

List<? super Long> superBound = new ArrayList<Long>();
takeExtend(superBound);
```

You might think that `T` is inferred to be `Long`. That would mean that you passed a `List<? super Long>` to a method declared like `void takeExtend(List<? extends Long> l)`, which seems wrong.

But `T` isn't inferred to be `Long`. If you specify `Long` explicitly as the type parameter, you'll see that it won't work:

```
Main.<Long>takeExtend(superBound);
```

What's actually happening is that `T` is inferred to be `? super Long`, so the generic type of the method is something like `void takeExtend(List<? extends ? super Long>)`. That means that everything in the list is something that extends an unknown super class of `Long`.

Comment: Regarding the first answer.
I totally agree with that, but in that way you are relying on the fact that we will be using the <? super T> argument for adding elements in it, and this is valid also if the adding is executing outside of a function. So, what it is not allowed is the adding, not the passing of the parameter to the function, which is allowed if we remove the adding statement from the function.
Regarding the second answer.
If T can be any type, why is it not valid also when the function is accepting super?

Comment: @acejazz  "So, what it is not allowed is the adding, not the passing of the parameter to the function, which is allowed if we remove the adding statement from the function." This isn't grammatical, so I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. The compiler doesn't allow passing a reference of that type as a parameter of that type (it also doesn't allow assignment in that case). *It has nothing to do what happens inside the method;* the compiler doesn't consider that. But the compiler disallows it for a reason, not just for fun. My example shows the reason.

Comment: Sorry for my bad grammar. As I got, the only logical reason to use a  <? super T> as argument in a function is for putting in it objects (Consumer-Super), so since you cannot do it with <? extends T> as actual parameter the compiler disallows it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

- Why is it not possible to pass a `<?>` or a `<? extends S>` to a function expecting `<? super T>`? (Question corrected for clarity: ? extends **S**).

The compiler wants to infer the T, which is the bottom limit, and it can't. Every class extends Object, but there is no universal inheritance tree bottom class, which the compiler could default to.

- Why is it possible to pass a `<?>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?

It's about inference. You can pass a `<?>` because the compiler can make something out of it. Namely, it can make Object out of T. The same happens with the following:

```
List<?> unbound = new ArrayList<>();
```

- Why is it possible to pass a `<? super T>` to a function expecting a `<? extends T>`?

Again, it's about inferring the upper limit now, so the compiler can default to Object. It's not interested in what ? is super to, nor whether it is super to anything at all.

Comment: It's not so much about inference as capturing. The compiler doesn't care what type `T` actually is. It just cares that all the references labeled as `T` are of the *same* type. After erasure, it's `Object`s all the way down anyway.

Comment: But if you have not only T, but also S, Q, R, V, W, etc, all having their places in a bigger hierarchy with many interrelations, then there is some inferring, no?

Comment: Sure. I was questioning only the idea that "[the compiler] can make Object out of T". I think that's a misleading idea. A generic method signature is in effect making a set of assertions about its type parameters. Type inference is possible if and only if there's a valid solution to that set of assertions. Actual types aren't really relevant, only the relationships between them.

Comment: To be honest I don't know if that's misleading or not. But it illustrates the logic very simply. @erickson gives his version of this at the end of his answer. I wanted to ask for sources or prove but don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking this stuff all night long, with the amazing help of your comments, trying to find an easy-to-remember solution.

This is what I got.
A method accepting a `<? extends T>`, to get T, must infer the upper limit of that hierarchy. Since in Java every class is extending Object, the compiler can rely on the fact that at least the upper limit is Object. So:

- if we pass a `<? extends T>`, the upper bound is already defined and it
  will use that one
- if we pass `<?>`, we don't know anything, but we know
  that every class extends Object, so the compiler will infer `Object`
- if we pass `<? super T>`, we know the lower bound, but since every class
  extends Object, the compiler infer `Object`.

A method accepting a `<? super T>`, to get T, must infer the lower limit of that hierarchy. In Java by default we can count on an upper bound, but not on a lower bound. So the considerations made in the previous case are not valid anymore. So:

- if we pass a `<? extends T>`, there is no lower bound, because the
  hierarchy can be extended as much as we want
- if we pass a `<?>`,
  there is no lower bound, because the hierarchy can be extended as
  much as we want
- if we pass a `<? super T>`, a lower bound is already
  defined, so we can use that one.

Recapping:

- a method accepting a `<? extends T>` can always rely on the fact that
  an upper bound exists and that is Object -> we can pass every bound to it
- a method accepting a `<? super T>` can infer a lower bound only if it is explicitly defined in the parameter -> we can only pass a `<? super T>`

Comment: Yes and no. Remember that the compiler doesn't at any point care what type T actually is. It's not 'Object' (or any other type, for that matter). It's just T.

Comment: I got your point.
The compiler doesn't infer Object, but in those case the compiler manage to do the erasure replacing T with Object.
How could I rephrase my answer for moving it from "Yes and No" to "Yes"? :)